# AngularJs - Add / remove icon on ng-click in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Goal: On ng-repeat, initial 'isSelected' from array has icon. If any item is clicked after display, prior item isSelected= false and has icon removed, current item has isSelected=true and gets icon.**

Current html:

```
<a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" id="{{style.id}}" data-ng-click="changeStyle(style.id)">
       <!-- only if item isSelected = true -->
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" id="skin-checked"></i>
       <!-- end selected icon -->
    {{style.name}}
 </a>
```

The controller:

1. changeStyle click event:

   ```
   $scope.changeStyle = function (style) {
       $scope.$emit('websiteStyleChange', style);
      // toDo: make all isSelected false, make item just clicked isSelected = true

   };
   ```
2. data:

   ```
   $scope.webStyles = [
       { name: "Default", id: "style_0", isSelected: true},
       { name: "One", id: "style_1", isSelected: false},
       { name: "Two", id: "style_2", isSelected: false}
   ];
   ```

Any ideas?

Thanks ...
.

Comment: Please mention in qquestion that What is the issue you are facing in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through your webStyles after each click and set all isSelected to false except the one that was just clicked. For example...

```
$scope.changeStyle = function (style) {
    angular.forEach($scope.webStyles, function (value, key) {
        value.isSelected = value.id === style ? true : false;
    });
};
```

Then, to show/hide your icon, use the ng-show directive..

```
<i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" id="skin-checked" ng-show="style.isSelected"></i>
```

Comment: Strike my response above: Your solution works, but it is webStyles not webstyles